# How to import org json calss in android studio

Tags: android

[image]

I tried to convert them to jar. But it occurred error
How to use in android studio? Have other solution?
Thank your help.

Answer (score 1):

add it in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.json:json:20160810'
}
```

view this page : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: Thank your help.I can run it.